# How to add items dynamically to VisualItemModel in QML?

Tags: javascript, qt, listview, qml

I have a custom qml element based on a textbox. I want that whenever the user presses on the last textbox in the VisualItemModel, a new textbox is added automatically. There is a way to do this with ListModel (using append()), but nothing with VisualItemModel. 
How to do this? Even Javascript will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like `VisualItemModel` wasn't really intended for dynamic management - it is a purely static construct.

`VisualItemModel` is a lazy and clumsy solution to get a list view to show different elements, cramming together the data and UI. If that is point, you can easily achieve this by using a standard `ListModel` and for the `ListView`:

```
ListView {
    anchors.fill: parent
    model: mod
    delegate: Loader {
        source: name + ".qml"
    }
}
```

Then you can append to the model like this:

```
mod.append({"name" : "ItemName"})
```

Then in the list view, the delegate will create the appropriate element for each list entry.

If you don't want to have separate sources for the items, you can wrap different items in a `Component` and in the `Loader` instead of `source` set the `sourceComponent: name`:

```
Component {
    id: c2
    Rectangle {
        width: 200
        height: 100
        color: "blue"
    }
}

....
mod.append({"name" : c2})
```

But in your case you don't seem to need different elements to have different UIs, therefore you don't really need `VisualItemModel` as well. Just make the view delegate a text box and append to a standard `ListModel` and you will get another text box.

Comment: Yep. That's what I realised finally that since delegate is a way how the UI looks, we don't need a VisualListItem at all. I had figured it out, but thanks for answering anyway.

Comment: Well, u can just use a numerical model, i.e. `model: 0`, so that, u can just write `model += 1` to add a new delegate.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo - that's the fastest way probably, but it is very inefficient because the entire view is redrawn as the number changes, whereas with a model only the changes are updated.

Comment: @ddriver Well, that's something that depends on your requirements. Surely it's more inefficient than the list but yeah, it's another way. :) The list provides build-in transition handling properties for addition/removal, which is also another point for that approach.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo - it is not just that - since the entire listview is redrawn, that means any text the OP might have entered in his text boxes will be lost each time he adds another - now that would be very backward. With a model it won't happen, plus the model can provide data storage for the text in those boxes.

Comment: Oh you're right. Didn't think about that. :) Still a solution for another use cases (surely not for that!)